# How to find the general solution of a differential equation of order $ 2 $ homogeneous with variable coefficients, without having a given solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following non-homogeneous order 2 differential equation with variable coefficients.

$$xy''+2y'-xy=2e^{2x}$$

I know the first step is to solve the homogeneous associate, i.e. $ xy '' + 2y'-xy = 0 $ but they didn't give me a solution to apply the order reduction. Still, I noticed that a solution is $ y_1 (x) = \frac {e ^ x} {x} $ and it was easy to solve the rest.

I know that there are equations that are very difficult to solve, and for this there is a qualitative theory, but in this particular case I imagine that there is a trick to know a solution of the homogeneous one that is not lucky. My question is, is there any trick for this type of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $u=xy$ the homogeneous DE reduces to:
$$u''-u=0$$

---

For the inhomogeneous equation:
$$xy''+2y'-xy=2e^{2x}$$
$$(xy)''-xy=2e^{2x}$$
$$u''-u=2e^{2x}$$